# Add custom filter to register data in array

Tags: php, plugin-development, filters, array

I would like to register a multi arry of data in a plugin and allows any developper to add new value to the array.

This multi array contains a name, and different value like this:

```
class Animation_Class {

    private $animations = array();

    function __construct() {
        $this->animations = apply_filters('add_animation', $this->animations);
    }

    // get custom animation array
    function get_animation_name() {
        return $this->animations;
    }
}


add_filter('add_animation', 'my_animation');

function my_animation($animation) {

    $animation[] = array(
        array('custom'=>'custom'),
        array(''=>'')
    );


    return $animation;

}

$my_class = new Animation_Class();
$animations = $my_class->get_animation_name();
print_r($animations);
```

What is the right way to add filter in a plugin (with a class maybe). My aim is to retrieve the array value with a key later on the main class. I think it's something simple but I have some difficulties to clearly understand or find example on filter.

Comment: So what does your `print_r` output? Is it working as expected? I'm having a hard time understanding the question. Can you provide more details?

Comment: It's working but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it. I don't use custom filter a lot and I want to be sure to correctly understand the right way to use it in terms of performance and implementation.